# Visual Studio Code extension that includes offline HTML

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible for a VSCode extension to include HTML that are written to disk somewhere (doesn't matter where) when the extension is installed, so that I can then open that HTML from links?

E.g. I want a link to the offline documentation for a function in its tooltip.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your extension can use the standard node apis to download the files. Then you can:

- Use the standard VS Code apis to open the file as a text document
- Use the `markdown.showPreview` command to open the file as a html preview in VS Code:

  ```
  import * as vscode from 'vscode';

  vscode.commands.executeCommand('markdown.showPreview', vscode.Uri.parse('file:///Users/you/path/to/file.html'));
  ```
- Use node apis to open the file in the user's standard web browser (again using the `file:` uri)

Comment: I actually found an even easier way - just put the documentation in your extension directory. It turns out a `vsix` package is basically just a zip of your extension directory. Then in my LSP server I just make a `file://` link relative to `argv[0]`. Unfortunately, when you click the link VSCode actually opens the HTML file itself rather than opening it in a browser. Not sure how to get around that!

Comment: I made another question for that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51059189/visual-studio-code-link-to-local-html-file

Comment: Points 2 and 3 answer that question