# Visual Studio Code link to local HTML file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a LSP server that returns hovers/tooltips containing links.

If I link to an HTML file on the web (`https://...`) when you click it it opens that link in the browser.

If I link to a local HTML file (`file://...`) it opens that HTML file in VSCode, as if you wanted to edit the file.

Is there any way to make it open the local HTML file in your browser?

**Edit 1**: I found [the code that handles this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/d2b6bbb46fbdf535e2c96b3e00ac56ac1d427a69/src/vs/editor/browser/services/openerService.ts#L44). Seems it just checks for `http`, `https` or `mailto` and opens those externally. Everything else it opens with VSCode.

**Edit 2**: Found an identical [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36452). Looks like there is code to work around this [here](https://github.com/alanz/vscode-hie-server/pull/21) and [here](https://github.com/alanz/vscode-hie-server/pull/64)

Comment: It depends on the default association with the file extension

Comment: No it doesn't - see my edit.

Comment: hmm, alright I admit I have no experience with this, but I know that some web libraries do what I wrote above

Comment: See response on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51049580/306149 You can use the standard node apis or 3rd party node libraries to open these files in the user's browser

Comment: That is also my question, lol.